# Coaxial cable terminology : how to read?

Tags: terminology, coax

I need to understand the nomenclature used for coaxial cable.

For example: UT-085-SS-SS, or UT-085-SS, or UT-085-NbTi

As far as I understood, the number 085 here is the total diameter of the cable in inches (thus 0.085 inches of diameter). The SS-SS means that the material is Stainless-Steel.

But how can I read it in general and not guess it ? I tried to find on internet but I didn't manage to find a place where it is well explained.

For example what is the difference between UT-085-SS-SS and UT-085-SS: both are in Stainless Steel apparently, but why one has it written twice?

What does the UT means?

Comment: Data sheet links please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UT stands for Uniform Tubes, the company that originally manufactured semi-rigid cable, it doesn't have any other particular meaning.

There is no rule for part numbers. Often they have a pattern, sometimes they are completely anarchic. Only the datasheet can tell you what all the characters mean.

Answer (score 0):

> For example what is the difference between UT-085-SS-SS and UT-085-SS: both are in Stainless Steel apparently, but why one has it written twice?

From some googling it looks like the SS-SS variant has stainless steel for both the outer and inner conductors, while the SS variant has a stainless outer conductor and a "SPCW" (which further googling tells me probably stands for silver plated copper wire) inner conductor.